# Environment variable into a Vue App at runtime

Tags: docker, vue.js

I have created VUE app with .env. files Its working fine with below docker file.

```
FROM node:14.15.0
WORKDIR /app
ADD ui ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm i --unsafe-perm node-sass@4.14.0
EXPOSE 8080

RUN chmod +x /app/deploy.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/deploy.sh"]
CMD ["dev"]
```

commands

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t vueapp .
docker run -d -p 80:8080 vueapp test
```

Now I want to build the vue app and create single docker image for all the environments and wanted to pass environment variable into a Vue App at runtime

In the application I am using environment variable like

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
process.env.VUE_APP_ABC_URL
process.env.VUE_APP_XYZ_URL
```

These variable are environment specific. When I run 'npm run build' its always production build and it will use .env.production file in the build time. If I use mode then it will become  environment specific image. Which I don't want. I want single image to run for all the environments.

below are the docker file.

```
# build stage
FROM node:14.15.0 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY ui /app


RUN npm install
RUN npm i --unsafe-perm node-sass@4.14.0

RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /opt/www
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build-stage /app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d


EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: could you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible when building the image to serve static files from nginx. There will be no node process to get the environment variables from, and the static files will not have access to the OS's environment.

The options are to build multiple images (one per environment) or use a node image and run the application that way. If you choose the latter, you can pass in environment variables as expected.